# Trying to make a table that converts decimal to binary and ASCII C++

Tags: c++, binary, hex, decimal, octal

I have to make a table that shows the values 1 through 127 converted to binary and decimal like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/ASCII-Table.svg):

Hexadecimal and Octal are optional.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    using namespace std;

int main()  {
    int dec;
    int binary_array [128];

    for (dec = 0; dec<128; dec++){

for (int I =0; I < 7; i++){

    binary_array[i]= dec % 2;
    cout<<binary_array[i];
    dec = dec / 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably lots of ideas.  You need to ask a more specific question about a more specific problem you have.  As it stands you've basically just asked for someone to finish your homework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bitset` to convert decimal to binary and then print out the results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    for(int i = 0; i <= 127; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " " << bitset<8>(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since using `bitset` is not an option, lets dissect your code and understand whats wrong with it.

```
using namespace std;

int main()  
{
    int dec;
    int binary_array [128];

    for (dec = 0; dec<128; dec++)
    {
        for (int I =0; I < 7; i++)
        {
            binary_array[i]= dec % 2;    <--OK
            cout<<binary_array[i];       <-- NOT OK, think carefully 
            dec = dec / 2;               <-- OK  
        }
    //now you have exited for loop, what is the value of dec?
    //think what happened to dec in the second for loop
    //your current logic will create a infinite loop
    }
}
```

Your logic is on the right path and if you think carefully, you will be able to do it yourself and feel good about it instead of copying available solution without trying to learn what went wrong. I would suggest you to try to think hard and implement. If you still cannot solve it, feel free to post updated code and let us know.

Comment: @RyanFasching Welcome the world of [non-functional requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement).

Comment: @RyanFasching i edited my post. Although I didn't post the solution, I posted hints to help you navigate

Comment: @sam2090 should the binary _array[i] be outside the for loop?

Comment: @RyanFasching yes, it should be outside the inner for loop to print out the bits. However, you still need to store the bits in the inner for loop. Think at what index are the bits stored in when you perform the mod operation.

Comment: @sam2090 they're stored in the array of length 128 right? And when I move cout<<binary_array[i] outside the inner for loop I get the compilation error: "name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]"

Comment: @RyanFasching, since your for loop iterates 8 times, you dont need 128 size array, 8 will do if you storing only the bits. If you are storing both decimal and binary, then you need 2d array. But thats not the issue. i is declared in the for loop so once you exit the loop, i is not in scope anymore. I would create another for loop and print out the bits. Also, I am assuming they were typos but if your code looks exactly as you posted, then you need to check the case of int I, I and i are different.